# Is there another way to achieve the functionality of std::optional without another object being created?

Tags: c++, stdoptional

```
class ScopedClass {
 public:
  ScopedClass() {
    cout << "constructor called\n";
  }

  ~ScopedClass() {
    cout << "destructor called\n";
  }

  ScopedClass(const ScopedClass &t)
  {
      cout << "copy constructor called\n";
  }

  ScopedClass(ScopedClass &&t)
  {
      cout << "move constructor called\n";
  }
}

std::optional<ScopedClass> check_and_return(bool condition) {
  if (condition == true)
    return std::make_optional(ScopedClass());
  return std::nullopt;
}

int main() {
  auto x = check_and_return(true);
}
```

I want a single `ScopedClass` object but `ScopedClass()` is copied/moved when I enclose it within `std::optional`. This means that the destructor is called when it's copied/moved and it's being called twice. Once inside `check_and_return` and once when `main` ends.

I would like the destructor to be called only when `main` ends.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or some alternate method not using `std::optional`?

Comment: What is your problem with moving? Do you have a proven performance problem with your code when you use std::optional?. I ask because as far as I know std::optional is quite good at avoiding making copies.

Comment: Do you want just `std::make_optional<ScopedClass>()`? Your code is creating a temporary `ScopedClass` which is moved into the optional, this defeats the purpose of using `make_optional`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [in-place overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional) of `std::make_optional` rather than the move overload.

```
std::optional<ScopedClass> check_and_return(bool condition) {
  if (condition == true)
    return std::make_optional<ScopedClass>(); // constructs ScopedClass in place with the arguments ()
  return std::nullopt;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

And yes there is another option, use std::make_unique/std::unique_ptr.
This will not move anything and call constructor and destructor only once.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ScopedClass {
public:
    ScopedClass() {
        std::cout << "constructor called\n";
    }

    ~ScopedClass() {
        std::cout << "destructor called\n";
    }

    ScopedClass(const ScopedClass& t)
    {
        std::cout << "copy constructor called\n";
    }

    ScopedClass(const ScopedClass&& t)
    {
        std::cout << "move constructor called\n";
    }

private:
    std::string some_resource;
};

std::unique_ptr<ScopedClass>  check_and_return(bool condition)
{
    if ( condition )
    {
        return std::make_unique<ScopedClass>();
    }

    return nullptr;
}

int main() 
{
    auto x = check_and_return(true);
}
```

Comment: Only downside (just lazy reason) for this method. We must check return value with `if(x != nullptr)`  not `if(x)` like std::optional

Comment: Not `if(x)` is ok. std::unique_ptr has an [implicit bool conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_bool), that's why I proposed this solution. Also the way I understand it no function calls will be made on ScopedClass (the name seems to imply some RAII resource managment). If call needs to be made the `std::optional` code would also have to have the `if (x)` code.

Comment: Thank you. I used to use  `if (x)`  for check value for std::unique_ptr but it's got unexpected result. I might did something wrong.